# Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : AnyObject]' with an index of type 'String'

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get some data from a JSON content(in my data.swift file) and assign it to "comments". Anyone know whats going wrong here and how I can fix it? Seems like a syntax issue that I'm having trouble with.

The error I am getting:
[image: The error I am getting]

```
import UIKit

class CommentsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var story = [String:AnyObject]()
var comments = [String:AnyObject]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    comments = story["comments"]

    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

It's not liking the `comments = story["comments"]` part.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is an error in your code, but the error message you're seeing is incorrect and misleading due to a Swift compiler bug.  The actual error message should read: `AnyObject is not convertible to [String:AnyObject]`.

`self.story["comments"]` returns an `AnyObject`.  To assign that value to `self.comments` you must first typecast `AnyObject` to the Dictionary type `[String:AnyObject]`.

For example:

```
self.comments = self.story["comments"] as! [String:AnyObject]
```

Comment: Thanks Darren. I did so and after running it crashed and gave me this message: Could not cast value of type 'Swift._SwiftDeferredNSArray' (0x10716fff0) to 'NSDictionary' (0x104b46d60). Tips on how to proceed?

Comment: The runtime error means that `story["comments"]` actually contains an array rather than the dictionary that you're expecting.  You can use the debugger to set a breakpoint and inspect the contents of `self.story`, or you can print the contents using `NSLog("%@", self.story)`.  Or, you can declare `self.comments` as an array instead of a dictionary (and change the typecast accordingly).

Answer (score 1):

According to your own declaration, `story` is a `[String:AnyObject]`. That means that `story["comments"]` is an AnyObject. But `comments` is a `[String:AnyObject]`, *not* an AnyObject. You can't assign an AnyObject where a `[String:AnyObject]` is expected.