# Swift: Getting dictionary value if I know the key

Tags: swift, dictionary, subscript

This should be super basic but I'm getting an error anyway.

`Cannot subscript a value of type 'Dictionary<String, AnyObject>' with an index of type 'String'`

Here's my code:

```
func createComments(attributes: [[String: AnyObject]], votes: [String: AnyObject], sid: Int) -> [Comment] {
    var comments: [Comment] = [Comment]()

    for commentAttributes in attributes {
        let comment = Comment()
        comment.commentId = commentAttributes["id"]
        comments.append(comment)
    }  

    return comments
}
```

I'm getting the error on this line:

`comment.commentId = commentAttributes["id"]`

As far as I can tell, commentAttributes should be a Dictionary with keys as Strings and values of AnyObject. I'm not sure how else to access the values of a Dictionary with a String key other than by using a String to subscript. What am I missing here?

Comment: Where is the definition of ``Comment``? Does it have a member ``commentId``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `if let` and cast it to proper type.

```
for commentAttributes in attributes {
        let comment = Comment()
        if let id = commentAttributes["id"] as? Int {
           comment.commentId = id
        }
        comments.append(comment)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course as soon as I ask the question I find the answer:

[Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : AnyObject]' with an index of type 'String'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33727025/cannot-subscript-a-value-of-type-string-anyobject-with-an-index-of-type-s)

I needed to typecast the value of commentAttributes["id"] so that it matched the type of comment.commentId

`comment.commentId = commentAttributes["id"] as! Int`

Comment: Thanks for posting the reference. Indeed a misleading error message.